# Customising the data displayed in second drop down menu depending on what has been selected in the first drop down (VBA PowerPoint)

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, powerpoint, sql-server-2014

I am using VBA in PowerPoint to pull across data from a SQL server into PowerPoint slides.

When the PowerPoint is opened, a first drop down displays in a form and lists names
Once a name is chosen it displays two new drop downs:
Second drop down displays Stage 1 information specific to name chosen
Third drop down displays Stage 2 information specific to name chosen

The second and third drop downs currently populate by reading what name has been chosen in the first drop down and searching for the words "Stage 1" (for the second drop down) and "Stage 2" (for the third drop down) and pulling this information off SQL.

Not all of the names in the first drop down menu will have items called Stage 1 and Stage 2, therefore, no data will be pulled across in the second and third drop downs.

Is there a way of creating something like this:

First drop down - Name 1 is chosen
Second drop down - Searches SQL for 'Name 1' and 'Stage 1'
Third drop down - Searches SQL for 'Name 2' and 'Stage 2'

First drop down - Name 2 is chosen
Second drop down - Searches SQL for 'Name 2' and '01'
Third drop down - Searches SQL for 'Name 2' and '02'

Thanks in advance!

Antonette

Comment: Are you struggling more with the "conditional lists", the drop downs, or the pulls from sql?